# What is a bridge rectifier doing in this TRIAC regulator?

Tags: voltage-regulator, triac, bridge-rectifier

Recently I purchased a TRIAC-based mains regulator and took a look inside. It's a very typical TRIAC regulator, except it contains a bridge rectifier (DB207S), the purpose of which is not clear to me at all. Can anyone enlighten me? What are `R4`, `R5` and `BR1` for?

Regulator schematic (load not shown):
[image: 1]

Comment: Tip: when you use the editor toolbar **CircuitLab** button to draw your schematic you can use the **Save and Insert** button to insert a PNG of the schematic into the post along with an edit link. There's no need for a CircuitLab account. No screengrab. No grid. It also means that others can copy and paste your schematic for further editing.

Comment: @Transistor Huh. I didn't know there was that option. I just made this in a standalone CircuitLab window, independent of StackExchange.

Comment: Yes, it's cool. You can now open my circuit, copy it, open your own, paste and then edit. I had to redraw yours!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ajjjpsz2P1Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fa1Ge0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Circuit redrawn with diodes instead of bridge rectifier.*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7Hjn5.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. Circuit redrawn with diodes arranged for clarity.*

(Thanks to @RusselH for a prompt to improve my understanding and explanation.)

It looks to me as though it's a rapid discharge circuit in case R2 is set very high.

- When [C] is going positive D1 and D2 are reverse biased and don't affect C1. D4 is forward biased so [B] is held at 0.7 V. D3 may contribute about half a volt to the initial charge on C1. D3 has no further effect through the positive half-cycle.
- If R2 is set very high and the DIAC doesn't turn on C1 will be left with a positive charge at the end of a positive half cycle.
- As the positive half-cycle nears the zero-cross [C] will fall below V<sub>C1</sub>. C1 will then discharge through D1, R4 leaving it ready to start a negative half cycle without a bias on C1.
- The negative half-cycle performs similarly with the functions of the diode pairs swapped.

Comment: On the positive half cycle, D3 and D4 conduct but have opposite polarities so so the combined drop from the capacitors point of view is zero. D4 completes the path to the capacitor's negative terminal so discharging to 0V. D1 and D2 perform the same operation for th negative half cycle.

Comment: So the function of D2 and D4 is to prevent charging C1 through D1 and D3, right?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 2):

@Transistor's answer identified that the circuit provides a rapid reset of C1 which it does.

I will address that the circuit also provides a mechanism to guarantee that the reset voltage is 0V across the timing capacitor for both positive and negative half cycles.

The circuit is reminiscent  of a solid state analog switch (Figure 1) used in rf circuits mainly. It can be used for audio if a loud pop can be tolerated during seitching.

The dc voltage drop from a to c will be zero even when the on voltage is applied to Vswitch. The circuit switches on with a positive voltage on Vswitch.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsdzid.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Applying this topology to the ciruit in the OP reveals the circuit in figure 3.

1. While the triac is conducting, the voltage across the circuit is essentially zero. The diodes D1 and D4 will reverse biased while Node 2 is positive preventing access to Node 1. If Node 2 is negative then diodes D2 and D3 will prevent access to Node 1. Node 2 will be at a voltage (say its negative) below which the diac is off. This voltage (from \$\pm\$ 5 to 10V) is uncertain and the discharge rate without the diodes is slow.
2. To provide accurate timing based on the R1,R2,C1 series string, the voltage across the capacitor must be set to zero each half cycle. The diode circuit forces this to happen.
3. At the end of the current half cycle the triac turns off allowing the voltage across the circuit to increase (positive in this example) The voltage at Node 2 is still negative but slowly rising to zero.
   The voltage across at Nodes 3 and 4 are increasing at the line voltage rate. D2 and D4 will be reverse biased. D1 (Node 2 voltage is still negative) and D3 will conduct.
4. This is the important point. The voltage across the diodes will be equal and opposite, **forcing the capacitor voltage to 0v**. The charging current is though R3, D1 and C1.
5. Once at zero volts, the capacitor will charge through R1 and R2. D3 will remain at 0.6V so D1 becomes reverse biased allowing the timing charge to continue from 0V.
6. On the negative half-cycle, Node 2 starts as a positive voltage and is discharged to zero through R4 and D2. D1 and D3 will be reverse biased.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fq3zrK.png)</sup>